# Visualforce Pages: Pulling contact roles from opportunity into related object

Tags: visualforce, opportunitycontactrole

I have a VF page that is supposed to pull the contact role information from the opportunity page. The code works on the opportunity page, but I need to add it to a related object (custom object). The related object has a lookup field (Parent_Opportunity__c).

VF (Updated):

```
<apex:page standardController="Parent_Opportunity__c"
    extensions="OpportunityContactRoleExtension">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Contact Roles" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.ContactRoles}" var="ContactRole">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.ContactRole.Contact.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.ContactRole.Contact.Phone}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Other Phone" value="{!Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.ContactRole.Contact.OtherPhone}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.ContactRole.Contact.Email}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Role" value="{!Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.ContactRole.Role}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Error (Updated):

> Error: Invalid field ContactRoles for SObject Opportunity

Comment: is `Parent_Opportunity__c` the API name of the custom object, as well? The `standardController` attribute takes the API name of the object. And then everywhere you have `Opportunity__r`, if the name of the field on the custom object is also `Parent_Opportunity__c`, you probably need to use `Parent_Opportunity__r`, unless you set the relationship name to be different from the field name.

Comment: "Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r" worked, but getting the following error: "Error: Invalid field ContactRoles for SObject Opportunity"

Comment: The correct reference to the child relationship would be Parent_Opportunity__c.Opportunity__r.OpportunityContactRoles. But when you use that, you're trying to use the Standard Controller, which doesn't support that up-then-down type of relationship. You'll need to query a list of the OppContactRoles in your controller extension and use that as the `value` of the `pageBlockTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query for the Opportunity Contact Roles in your controller extension. So here's how the controller extension might look:

**OpportunityContactRoleExtension**

```
public class OpportunityContactRoleExtension {

    public List<OpportunityContactRole> contactRoles {get; set;}
    private final Parent_Opportunity__c parentOpp;
    // put any fields you need to use in the controller extension that 
    // don't appear on the VF page in this list
    private final List<String> fieldList = new List<String>{'Opportunity__c','Sample_Field__c'};

    public OpportunityContactRoleExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cntrl) {
        cntrl.addFields(fieldList);
        this.parentOpp = (Parent_Opportunity__c)cntrl.getRecord();
        this.contactRoles = [SELECT Id, Role, ContactId, Contact.Name, Contact.Phone, Contact.OtherPhone, Contact.Email
                            FROM OpportunityContactRole
                            WHERE OpportunityId = :parentOpp.Opportunity__c];
    }
}
```

Then in your VF, the `pageBlockTable` opening tag becomes:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactRoles}" var="ContactRole">
```

and then strip everything before `ContactRole` from the values for all your `<apex:column>`s, eg:  `value="{!ContactRole.Contact.Name}"`

Comment: Whoops! `Parent_Opportunity__c`. I fixed it, and the variable reference on the same line, above. It's casting the generic SObject that comes from StandardController.getRecord() to the specific object type you're working with. You'll also want to remove `,'Sample_Field__c'` from `fieldList` unless you actually have such a field. It's just there to demonstrate the syntax for a multi-item list of strings.

Comment: Based on what you said above, you shouldn't need to change the `WHERE` clause. If the object is `Parent_Opportunity__c` and the field on that object is `Opportunity__c`, it should work as-is.

Comment: Add `set;`  to the variable declaration in the controller extension. I think I took it out after testing, thinking it wasn't necessary if just displaying.

Comment: sorry. I didn't follow that :(

Comment: Look at the second line of code above. Where  it used to say {get;} it now says {get; set;} . Make the same change.